# Why is running 'setfallback' in lua giving an error

Tags: lua

I am new to Lua Programming and been reading this documentation : https://www.lua.org/spe.html. Can someone please tell me why I am getting the following error when I run the following code snippet?:

```
  n=0                            -- counter of temporary variables
  T={}                           -- table of temporary variables

  function arithfb(a,b,op)
   local i=op .. "(" .. a.name .. "," .. b.name .. ")"
   if T[i]==nil then             -- expression not seen yet
     n=n+1
     T[i]=create("t"..n)         -- save result in cache
     print(T[i].name ..'='..i)
   end
   return T[i]
  end

  setfallback("arith",arithfb)   -- set arithmetic fallback

  function create(v)             -- create symbolic variable
   local t={name=v}
   setglobal(v,t)
   return t
  end

  create("a") create("b") create("c") create("z")

  while 1 do                     -- read expressions
   local s=read()
   if (s==nil) then exit() end
   dostring("E="..s)             -- execute fake assignment
   print(s.."="..E.name.."\n")
  end
```

lua: parser.lua:14: attempt to call a nil value (global 'setfallback')
stack traceback:
    parser.lua:14: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have managed to find a very old specification of Lua, probably Lua 2. Before metatables were introduced, you'd had to assign a global fallback function for a specific operation, but now metatables allow you to define a local fallback for an operation performed on concrete tables, via metatables.

You should read the current documentation for [Lua 5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html) or check the value of `_VERSION` if you are unsure about the version of the interpreter you are using.

Answer (score 2):

That code was meant for Lua 2.1, as mentioned in that paper. It uses fallbacks, which have since been replaced by metatables.

Here is an incarnation of that code that runs in Lua 5.1+:

```
local MT={}
local V={}
local N=0

local function var(name)
 local t={name=name}
 V[name]=t
 _G[name]=t
 return setmetatable(t,MT)
end

local function S(a)
 if type(a)=="table" then return a.name else return a or 0 end
end

local function arithfb(a,b,op)
 local i=op .. "(" .. S(a) .. "," .. S(b) .. ")"
 if V[i]==nil then N=N+1; V[i]=var("t"..N,N); print(V[i].name ..'='..i) end
 return V[i]
end

local t={"add", "sub", "mul", "div", "unm", "pow"}
for i,v in next,t do
 MT["__"..v]=function (a,b) return arithfb(a,b,v) end
end

local function vars(s)
 for x in string.gmatch(s,"(%w+)") do var(x) end
end

vars"a,b,c"
return (a*a+b*b)*(a*a-b*b)/(a*a+b*b+c)+(a*(b*b)*c)
```